# Resizing the sum operator

Tags: fonts, math-operators

The following simple expression produces a sum operator as in (1). But I want it to be bigger like in (2), of course, without altering the size of inner braces. Any suggestion?

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
   $$\sum_{i=1}^{N_P}\biggl(X^{(i)}-Y^{(i)}\biggr)^2$$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please have a look on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to ;-)

Comment: There is no reason for using `\bigg` in the first expression; if you use simple `(` and `)`, the size of the summation symbol is just right. And there's no reason for increasing the size of `\sum` under any circumstance, in my opinion.

Comment: @egreg well, I actually need it bigger

Comment: @Tnoor No, you _want_ it bigger. You didn't give any reason why it _has to_ be bigger. The problem is that there's no such reason, as far as I know.

Comment: @tohecz My reason might seem unreasonable to someone else, or maybe you are right in speculating that I don't really have any. With due respect, why there always have to be a reason?-The fact here is not why, the fact is how.

Comment: @Tnoor The fact _is_ "why", because when I copy edit articles and other works done by people who think they "know the things" and they actually do not, it is very painful, takes a lot of time, and costs money to the university which I work for. That's one of the reasons why many people here want everybody to use LaTeX to do _good_ typography, and not to defile their documents.

Comment: to moderator -- i accidentally flagged a comment i meant to upvote.  sorry.  my ipad and i don't communicate very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%
\newcommand*{\Resize}[2]{\resizebox{#1}{!}{$#2$}}%
 \begin{document}

    \[\sum_{i=1}^{N_P}\biggl(X^{(i)}-Y^{(i)}\biggr)^2\]

    \[\mathop{\Scale[2]{\sum}}_{i=1}^{N_P}\biggl(X^{(i)}-Y^{(i)}\biggr)^2\]


 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello! Please note that we prefer to point out other mistakes to the OP that are not related to the issue that is being solved, because it improved their overall knowledge of LaTeX. [It is advised to use `\[ ... \]` rather than `$$ ... $$`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).

Answer (score 0):

Compile with LuaLaTeX (or XeLaTeX).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\begin{document}
\[ \sum_{i=1}^{N_P} \bigl(X^{(i)} - Y^{(i)}\bigr)^2 \]
\end{document}
```